# What is a Filer officer?

Tags: meaning

Source: http://thefreethoughtproject.com/cop-shoots-mans-service-dog-9-year-sons-birthday/#WyU0h1jKvjFGLaLT.01

> A dog is dead, and its owner is alleging trigger-happy police work after **a Filer officer** shot the animal Saturday outside his home.

What is a Filer officer?

Comment: Filer is the name of the city: [Filer, Idaho](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filer,_Idaho).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An officer from (well, employed by the police department of) [Filer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filer,_Idaho), Idaho, where the incident took place.